# AmazonServiceException: Invalid region us-west-2 specified. Only us-east-1 is supported

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, autoscaling

Getting below error while creating scaling policy with alarm for autoscaling group.

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Invalid region us-west-2 specified. Only us-east-1 is supported. (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 7582...
```

**Scaling Policy**

```
for (AutoScalingGroup asg: autoScalingGroups){
PutScalingPolicyRequest spr = new PutScalingPolicyRequest();
        spr.setAutoScalingGroupName(asg.getAutoScalingGroupName());
        spr.setPolicyName("testautoscalePolicy");
        spr.setAdjustmentType("ChangeInCapacity");
        spr.setScalingAdjustment(2);
PutScalingPolicyResult result1 = autoClient.putScalingPolicy(spr);
```

**Alarm**

```
 PutMetricAlarmRequest putMetricAlarmRequest = new PutMetricAlarmRequest();
        putMetricAlarmRequest.setAlarmName("Scaleup-alarm");
        putMetricAlarmRequest.setMetricName("CPUUtilization");
        putMetricAlarmRequest.setComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold);
        putMetricAlarmRequest.setStatistic(Statistic.Sum);
        putMetricAlarmRequest.setUnit(StandardUnit.Percent);
        putMetricAlarmRequest.setThreshold(40.0);
        putMetricAlarmRequest.setPeriod(60);
        putMetricAlarmRequest.setEvaluationPeriods(1);
List actions = new ArrayList();
actions.add(result1.getPolicyARN());
putMetricAlarmRequest.setAlarmActions(actions);

AmazonCloudWatchClient amazonCloudWatchClient = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(awscredentials);
PutMetricAlarmResult alarmResult = amazonCloudWatchClient.putMetricAlarm(putMetricAlarmRequest);
```

What's the missing part here? Please help!

Comment: Is that the only code for alarm or is there more code in there?

Comment: @error2007s I have already created Launch configs and autoscale group. I am fetching autoscale group and trying to add scaling policy to it. For alarm Yes, I have that much code. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to setup this variable in your alarm EC2_REGION=eu-west-1 then I guess the error will go

Comment: My Autoscaling group is in US_WEST_2 region. I tried to set cloudwatchclient region to eu-west-1, still no success.

Comment: So your ASG is in us-west-2 so set the above variable to EC2_REGION=eu-west-2.

Comment: I am trying this - cloudWatch.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)); giving same error and not able to see region you mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117812/discussion-between-rohitkadam19-and-error2007s).

Comment: It seems obvious enough that you are sending a request (implicitly?) to us-east-1 that you need to be sending to us-west-2.    I have *no* idea why EU regions are repeatedly being mentioned in this context.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am sending request to US-WEST-2, I tried us-east-1 because it was mentioned in error. In either case request is not working

Comment: At `actions.add(result1.getPolicyARN());`, what's the value from `result1.getPolicyARN()`?